# XPages Managed Bean setter not firing on checkbox change

Tags: xpages

I've created a custom control that is basically a checkbox. I want the checkbox read the value of the dataSource I pass in - which would be a managed bean.  I can get the checkbox field to read from the bean but I'm not seeing anything happen when I change the checkbox.  It doesn't look like the setter in the bean ever gets called.

The key snippets of my bean are:

```
private boolean categoriesOn;
...

public boolean isCategoriesOn() {
    System.out.println("Getting On Value");
    return categoriesOn;
}
public void setCategoriesOn(boolean newValue) {
    System.out.println("Setting On : " + newValue);
    this.categoriesOn = newValue;
}
```

The control on the XPage looks like this:

```
<xp:checkBox id="flipSwitch"
                    styleClass="onoffswitch-checkbox"
                    value="${compositeData.dataSource}"
                    checkedValue="#{javascript:true}"
                    uncheckedValue="#{javascript:false}">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:checkBox>
```

I pass the bean to the custom control with a custom property:

```
<xc:crtl_toggleSwitch
                dataSource="#{exhibitorInfo.categoriesOn}"
                refreshID="computedField6">
            </xc:crtl_toggleSwitch>
```

dataSource is set to use Methodbinding.

I've tried with partial and full refresh.  I'm just not sure what I need to do to get the changed value back into the bean.

thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546635/binding-a-checkbox-control-to-a-bean-in-xpages

Comment: The title of your question says combobox but the content says checkbox...

Comment: Try putting the code in the getter not the setter (or in addition to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in Peter's answer on the question Per linked to, checkboxes cannot be bound directly to booleans (which is admittedly ridiculous). Add these methods:

```
public String getCategoriesOnAsString(){
 return isCategoriesOn() ? "1" : "0";
}

public void setCategoriesOnAsString(String value){
 setCategoriesOn("1".equals(value));
}
```

Then bind your checkbox to `#{exhibitorInfo.categoriesOnAsString}`, and set `checkedValue` and `uncheckedValue` to `"1"` and `"0"`, respectively.

Comment: Yeah - the "can't bind to boolean" is unfortunate