# Binding XPages check box group to managed bean

Tags: jsf, xpages, lotus-domino

How does one go about binding the value of an XPages "Check Box Group" to a Managed Bean so that multiple values can be loaded and saved without binding each check box individually? I'm able to bind text values on the page just fine, but nothing seems to work with the check box group. I have tried using a String with comma separated values, <strike>which is how it is stored in a Notes document</strike>, as well as a Vector to no avail.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20481436/785061

Comment: See my comment below: on 901 a getter/ setter with a `java.util.ArrayList` should work. BTW: you say that it's stored in Notes as a comma separated string. That is not correct: by default it should be stored as a multi-value list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with checkboxes is that value binding to bean fields isn't not consistent. Single value -> Set string value. Multiple values -> Set list value.

At least it was like that a while back.

This is the technique I use to work around the issue:
http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2012/06/multi-value-fields-and-beans-in-xpages.html

Comment: That's what I thought too. But... just tested this with a basic setup and the values (now) always seem to be send as a `java.util.ArrayList` , also if only a single value is checked. This was on a 9.0.1 server.

Comment: Ahh.. Then IBM might have fixed it. Thanks for testing :)

Comment: Thanks guys. We're not on 9.0.1 yet, but good to know that they've changed this.